# How to show balloon only 1 balloon in 1 map?

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I have map view which contain a lot of pin of place , each pin can show balloon over its . but when I press another pin , the balloon of the old one isn't close automatic , so I want to clear balloon every time before other balloon will show

(I extends BalloonItemizedOverlay)

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code removes all BalloonOverlayItems from the map:

```
  MapView.removeViews(0, MapView.getChildCount());
```

It is the equivalent of MapView.getOverlays().clear() (used for regular overlays), the code above works for a map that contains Balloon overlays.

Answer (score 1):

From [BallonItemizerOverlay.java](http://code.google.com/p/cs294/source/browse/LiveRadar/src/cs294s/liveradar/ui/BalloonItemizedOverlay.java?r=25)

```
        /**
         * Sets the visibility of this overlay's balloon view to GONE. 
         */
        private void hideBalloon() {
                if (balloonView != null) {
                        balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
        }

        /**
         * Hides the balloon view for any other BalloonItemizedOverlay instances
         * that might be present on the MapView.
         * 
         * @param overlays - list of overlays (including this) on the MapView.
         */
        private void hideOtherBalloons(List<Overlay> overlays) {

                for (Overlay overlay : overlays) {
                        if (overlay instanceof BalloonItemizedOverlay<?> && overlay != this) {
                                ((BalloonItemizedOverlay<?>) overlay).hideBalloon();
                        }
                }

        }
```

Comment: yes I have this section code also and it works, but it have some problem when I press pin1 (show balloon1) and then I go to other activity and then back to map page , balloon1 still show although I press pin2 ( it will show balloon1 and balloon2) so I want to shut balloon1 down when I go to other activity , please help.

Comment: If you want to remove the other balloons call `mapOverlays.clear(); mapView.invalidate();`. I'll have to see your code, specifically what's done in onResume(). You'll have to hide/remove the balloon1 overlay item there.

Comment: I try mMapView.getOverlays().clear();mMapView.invalidate(); in onResume and the result is pin is gone but balloon still show what should I do?

Comment: Again, I can't say without seeing your code. You probably have to  `mapView.getOverlays().remove(i)`, then call invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but I think I was facing the same problem today.

When you remove items by using `mapView.getOverlays().clear()`, all items are removed.
But, if you look at the method 'createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay'  in `BalloonItemizedOverlay.java` you'll see the line `mapView.addView(balloonView, params);`, so `mapView` keep a reference of the balloon as child. That why your pin is gone but the balloon1 still show.

The quick fix will be to remove all instance of`BalloonOverlayView` with the methode `mapView.removeViewAt()` after deleted items. Also depend of your implementation maybe you will need to keep the current displayed balloon.